# How to list merge conflicts on origin that are not on local?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, bitbucket-server

Stash is rejecting my pull request due to merge conflicts.  So I create a merge branch, merge destination into the merge branch, (there's nothing to commit), push anyway and open the pull request again.  Still rejected for conflicts.  I've deleted and recreated 3 times, and getting the same results each time.

git mergetool reports no conflicts on local merge branch.

What can I do to figure out what the conflicts are on the remote?

Comment: Stash won't reject the creation of a pull request due to conflicts, it will only reject the merge once it's created, so you can create the pull request anytime (and should only need to do it once only). Could you describe the branch names and commands you used?

Comment: Turned out there were no conflicts.  Stash was displaying a conflict complaint but we never figured out why.  Merge was a fast-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't create a new branch to resolve conflicts. Instead you merge the target branch into your pull requests's branch:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout my_pr_branch
git merge origin/master
<resolve conflicts and commit the resolution>
git push origin my_pr_branch`
```

If you keep seeing conflicts at stash – someone else has pushed something new to conflict with you at destination.